# Why setter method when getter method enough in PHP OOP

Tags: php, object-oriented

I am practicing OOP with PHP, and I am struck at setter and getter methods.

I can directly access the class properties and methods with getter method then what's the use of setter method?

See my example.

```
<?php
class MyClass{
    public $classVar = "Its a class variable";
    public function Getter(){
        return $this -> classVar;
    }
}
$obj = new MyClass;
echo $obj -> Getter();
?>
```

Comment: If you don't need to set the property from outside the object's scope, then you don't need a setter.

Comment: if u make a property public then you are exposing the internals of your class which will make your code depends on "How" the class does something instead of "What" it does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your class variable `$classVar` shouldn't be `public`.

One of the reasons for having getters and setters is to hide your implementation. By making the class variable public you are exposing your implementation thus negating this benefit.

Make the variable `private`.

Comment: You mean to say its the concept of Encapsulation. Hiding the implementation.